# Extract cell values from multi body html table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have multiple `tables` in my HTML. Then there are multiple `tbody` in required table. However, I am able to select specific table and tbody using

```
tables = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "annotation"}).findAll("tbody",{"class":"annotation"})
```

But, after that I am unable to get the `tr` & `td` information present in body. Because if I print result of above line it gives

```
<tbody class="annotation"></tbody>
```

And when I try `rows = tables.find_all('tr')` it returns null.

Entire HTML is pretty big and difficult to insert here so I have added an image and I want to extract the values where my cursor is in given image

[image: HTML]

Answer (score 1):

could you provide the link at least?

also keep in mind, you need to do it element-wise. `find` returns a single element. `findAll` returns a list, even if the list only contains one item.

so my wild guess is:

```
tables = soup.find("table", {"class": "annotation"}).find_all("tbody",{"class":"annotation"})[0]
rows = tables.findAll("tr")
```

Oh, I noticed that you're the guy from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241940/python-request-api-is-not-fetching-data-inside-table-bodies/45244024#45244024). I tried to scrape the webpage in that thread and It requires JavaScript execution. 
So my advice is using the code from the other thread combined with this. let me know what happened with you so we could fiddle more.