# Python request api is not fetching data inside table bodies

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib2

I am trying to scrap a webpage to get table values from text data returned from requests response.

```
</thead>
 <tbody class="stats"></tbody>
 <tbody class="annotation"></tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Actually there is some data present inside `tbody` classes but `I am unable to access that data using requests.

Here is my code

```
server = "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/QuickGO/GProtein"
header = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; 
rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}
payloads = {'ac':'Q9BRY0'}
response = requests.get(server, params=payloads)

print(response.text)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
#print(soup)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml') should be BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

Comment: Yeah. But, I am printing response.text which I have showed above where I am not getting data inside body.

Comment: The page content doesn't appear to be accessible using BeautifulSoup. Do you need content from many pages or could you click on the 'Download' button with your mouse?

Comment: Yeah. http://www.ebi.ac.uk/QuickGO/GProtein?ac=Q9BRY0 is the page. And I came to know requests and beautifulsoup api can't fetch and parse javascript rendered blogs. Any suggestion how to do that? @BillBell

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I'm beginning to lose interest in routine scraping involving products like selenium, and then beyond that I wasn't sure it would work. This approach does.

You would only do this, in this form at least, if you had more than a few files to download.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> form = '''<form method="POST" action="GAnnotation"><input name="a" value="" type="hidden"><input name="termUse" value="ancestor" type="hidden"><input name="relType" value="IPO=" type="hidden"><input name="customRelType" value="IPOR+-?=" type="hidden"><input name="protein" value="Q9BRY0" type="hidden"><input name="tax" value="" type="hidden"><input name="qualifier" value="" type="hidden"><input name="goid" value="" type="hidden"><input name="ref" value="" type="hidden"><input name="evidence" value="" type="hidden"><input name="with" value="" type="hidden"><input name="source" value="" type="hidden"><input name="q" value="" type="hidden"><input name="col" value="proteinDB,proteinID,proteinSymbol,qualifier,goID,goName,aspect,evidence,ref,with,proteinTaxon,date,from,splice" type="hidden"><input name="select" value="normal" type="hidden"><input name="aspectSorter" value="" type="hidden"><input name="start" value="0" type="hidden"><input name="count" value="25" type="hidden"><input name="format" value="gaf" type="hidden"><input name="gz" value="false" type="hidden"><input name="limit" value="22" type="hidden"></form>'''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(form, 'lxml')
>>> action = soup.find('form').attrs['action']
>>> action 
'GAnnotation'
>>> inputs = soup.findAll('input')
>>> params = {}
>>> for input in inputs:
...     params[input.attrs['name']] = input.attrs['value']
...     
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post('http://www.ebi.ac.uk/QuickGO/GAnnotation', data=params)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> open('temp.htm', 'w').write(r.text)
4082
```

The downloaded file is what you would receive if you simply clicked on the button.

Details for the Chrome browser:

- Open the page in Chrome.

  Right-click on the 'Download' link.

  Select 'Inspect'.

  Select 'Network' in the Chrome _Developer_ menu (near the top), and then 'All'.

  Click on 'Download' in the page.

  --> Click on 'Download' in the newly opened window.

  'quickgoUtil.js:36' will appear in the 'Initiator' column.

  Click on it.

  Now you can set the breakpoint on `form.submit();` by clicking on its line number.

  Click on 'Download' again; execution will pause at breakpoint.

  In the right-hand window notice 'Local'. One of its contents is `form`. You can expand it for the contents of the form.

You want the `outerHTML` property of this element for the information used in the code above, namely for its `action` and name-value pairs. (And the implied information that POST is used.)

Now use the requests module to submit a request to the website.

Here's a list of the items in `params` in case you want to make other requests.

```
>>> for item in params.keys():
...     item, params[item]
... 
('qualifier', '')
('source', '')
('count', '25')
('protein', 'Q9BRY0')
('format', 'gaf')
('termUse', 'ancestor')
('gz', 'false')
('with', '')
('goid', '')
('start', '0')
('customRelType', 'IPOR+-?=')
('evidence', '')
('aspectSorter', '')
('tax', '')
('relType', 'IPO=')
('limit', '22')
('col', 'proteinDB,proteinID,proteinSymbol,qualifier,goID,goName,aspect,evidence,ref,with,proteinTaxon,date,from,splice')
('q', '')
('ref', '')
('select', 'normal')
('a', '')
```

Comment: could you elaborate where did you find `var postRequest = this.postRequest = function(url, params, inputparams)`?

Comment: thanks for the elaboration. but when I click download I don't get quickgoUtil.js:36 in Initiator, I get nothing. then a popup shows then If I click download again in the popup I get another initiator not the one you got..

pics:
http://imgur.com/a/fKskU

Comment: Can I verify that you are using 'Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build)(64-bit)' of Chrome?

Comment: I'm asking because I'm in the same boat as the next guy. I try to scrape a video from a [page](http://okanime.com/animes/one-piece/episodes/one-piece-314) but Its iframes that have the video doesn't show unless I render javascript and I don't want to use selenium. so any thoughts about how can I get the iframe['src'] without using selenium?

Comment: I accidentally omitted a step! 'Click on download in the newly opened window.' Please see above.

Comment: yea I finally got there! thank you bro. one last question, can you tell me if the same concept could work in [this page](http://okanime.com/animes/one-piece/episodes/one-piece-314)?

I want to load the iframes so I can get into their 'src'  but without selenium.

Comment: It could very well work but the exact sequence of steps would almost certainly be different.

Comment: sorry to bother you... but if you could help me do that cause I've been trying since your comment but couldn't, I made [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287805/how-to-scrape-iframe-that-didnt-show-directly-in-beautifulsoup-require-using) but nobody answered

Answer (score 0):

I get from your comment above that you're dealing with javascript. in order to scrape & parse javascript you could use selenium, Here is a snippet that could help in your case:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url =''

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
soup.prettify()
```

you will have to install ChromeDriver & Chrome Browser tho.
if you want you could use headless browser like PhantomJs so you wouldn't have to deal with the whole chrome browser every time you execute the script.