# how to scrape iframe that didn't show directly in BeautifulSoup & require using selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape a video from [this site](http://okanime.com/animes/one-piece/episodes/one-piece-314). however, I tried to get its URL directly from the `<iframe src="">` tag but I didn't find it in the page source after I scraped it using requests & BeautifulSoup.
I used this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ok = requests.get('http://okanime.com/animes/one-piece/episodes/one-piece-314')
parse = BeautifulSoup(ok.content, 'html5lib')

for url in parse.find_all('iframe'):
    print(url['src'])
```

then I though there could be some javascript involved then I tried Selenium to make sure, and indeed there is javascript. and I scraped them using selenium.

so here come my question. could I scrape such thing without using selenium?

could I send a second get request using requests in order to get those iframes?

Comment: What do you do to get what you want from the site using keystrokes and/or mouse gestures?

Comment: no just get the browser source then parse it. `soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")`

Comment: Why would this work for me if it doesn't work for you?